# Can I lay new foundations under 'Permitted Development' of a barn?

Tags: barn

If a barn has 'Permitted Development' (UK), I understand that structural modifications can take place (new walls, windows etc.), but can, if needed, new foundations be made?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding “Local building codes or advice limited to your area” are specifically listed as off topic in the help center.

Comment: @Tyson - If you read [the on-topic page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you'll see that "National building codes (of any country)." are specifically on topic. Last I checked, the UK was a country, not a locality.

Comment: @AndyT interesting... from a little farther down on the very page that you linked is the text I copied and pasted that says it’s off topic.  There seems to be some disagreement on the very page you linked.  Typically tho questions about what’s allowed under a specific permit do get closed as off-topic, mainly because one inspector or dept may read the rules differently than the next, if it’s a permitting question the best answer will be obtained from the AHJ.

Comment: I think, in this case, that it's fairly unambiguous:  it's a non-local building code who's rules cannot be read differently.

Comment: ... and more to the point, relating to the whole existence of StackExchange, is that the question, and answer, would be *helpful* to future readers...

Comment: @Tyson - That page has no disagreement. *National* building codes are on topic, *Local* building codes are not. It's pretty clear.